# How to use a second database in Silverstripe

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

i tried to declare a new db in _config.php

```
global $databaseConfig2;
$databaseConfig2 = array(
    "type" => 'MySQLDatabase',
    "server" => 'localhost',
    "username" => 'local_dbuser',
    "password" => 'aPassword',
    "database" => 'local_db2',
    "path" => '',
);
```

and then switch to the second db in the controller i need to use it:

```
public function doStuff() {
    global $databaseConfig, $databaseConfig2;

    // connect to DB 2
    DB::connect($databaseConfig2);

    // create a query.. this will go to "databaseB"
    $query = new SQLQuery("*", "MyTable");

    $result = $query->execute();

    // do something with the result...

    // when done, switch back to the regular DB Config
    DB::connect($databaseConfig);
}
```

i took this from http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/customising-the-cms/show/13692 . but it doesn't work.

also, i tried this code, to insert any values from a form into this separate db.

SecureFormInput.php

```
class SecureFormInput extends DataObject{

    global $databaseConfig, $databaseConfig2;

    DB::connect($databaseConfig2);

    private static $db = array(
        'FirstName' => 'Varchar',
        'SureName'  => 'Varchar',
        'OtherName' => 'Varchar',
        'DateOfBirth' => 'Date',
        'Gender'    => 'Boolean'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'SecureForm' => 'SecureForm'
    );

    DB::connect($databaseConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that the other database isn't being managed by SilverStripe so you cannot use "ORM" methods.  You can use regular SQL statements via DB::Query('SELECT * FROM Table'), for example this code could be placed / replace the Page.php init function...

```
function init() {

    parent::init();

    //...

    global $databaseConfig, $databaseConfig2;
    DB::connect($databaseConfig2);// connect to DB 2

    $query = DB::Query("SELECT MyData FROM MyTestTable");
    foreach ($query as $row) var_dump($row);

    DB::connect($databaseConfig);// when done, switch back to the regular DB 

    //...
}
```

If you want to write data then it will again need to use a full INSERT or UPDATE statement within the DB::Query

Comment: when i run dev/build it show an error becouse of using global right after the class: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL

Comment: i tested the above code in an init function of the page class,it isn't supposed to be "class" content.  I've updated the above to clarify that.

Comment: i am using a DataObject to store the data from a form, so first i need to build the database fields(of course i can make it manually) but i'm not sure if the relationship will work anymore. The init function can be declared only in controller..right ? Thanks

Comment: The init function is part fo the parent object for a controller, which is why I'm calling parent::init() - but you can create a function called "init" in any class.